# Question about editting very long sentence with python

Tags: python-3.x

I want examine the hexa sentence.

```
with open("C:/python_tria/HEX/sample/test.zip", "rb+") as f:
    stri = str(f. read())
sta=stri.find('this is where to start')
end=stri.find('this is where to end')
```

My plan is extract the part between 'sta' through 'end'.
What is the solution I could take?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `re.findall` on the file text to find what you are looking for:

```py
with open("C:/python_tria/HEX/sample/test.zip", "rb+") as f:
    stri = str(f.read())

matches = re.findall(r'this is where to start.*?this is where to end', stri, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches[0])  # print the first match
```

Comment: i made another line
find=stri[sta:end]